# The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests in Angular Application

Tags: angular, process, command-line-interface, period, seconds

I am getting the below timeout exception in `Angular CLI`

`TimeoutException`: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout(Task task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+c__DisplayClass2_0+b__0>d.MoveNext()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me. I set it to 80 seconds. It works 100% correct
I change it in Startup.cs

```
'using System;
app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 80);
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });'
```

Comment: I search for ans and spent lot of time in Internet and Get the Perfect Ans Ever.